# What's the relation between the trace and the range of a projector?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Knowing that, if $P$ is a projector it'll be:
$$P=P^2, ~~~P=P^\dagger$$
I was wandering if we can identify a relation between the dimention and the trace of a projector matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume we're talking about finite dimensional vector spaces here. The eigenvalues of $P$ are all $1$ or $0$ because it's a projection. The trace remains the same if you diagonalise $P$, so it will be equal to the multiplicity of eigenvalue $1$, that is the rank of $P$.

Comment: that's true! I have to revise the properties that a matrix maintains after having been diagonalized

Comment: By the way, why do you define your projector to be Hermitian?

Comment: that's how it's defined on my book a linear projector: linear operator on hilbert space such that $P=P^2, P=P^\dagger$

Answer (score 2):

The trace of $P\in B(H)$ agrees with the dimension of $PH$, even if $H$ is infinite dimensional, and for $PH$  finite or infinite-dimensional. Since $P=P^\dagger P$ is positive, the trace of $P$ is always defined (whether finite or infinite).

So, if $\{e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $PH$, we may complete it to an orthonormal basis of $H$ $\{e_n\}\cup\{f_m\}$. Then 
$$
\operatorname{Tr}\,(P)=\sum_n\langle e_n|P|e_n\rangle+\sum_m\langle f_m|P|f_m\rangle=\sum_n\langle e_n|P|e_n\rangle=\sum_n\langle e_n|e_n\rangle=\dim(PH). 
$$

Comment: Pro Argerami,I only know the definition of trace of a trace class operator.If $P$ is not a trace class operator,can we define $Tr(P)=\sum_{x\in E}\langle Px,x\rangle,$where $E$ is any orthonormal basis of $H$.

Comment: You need $P $ positive.

Comment: I wonder in which book give the definition of trace of a positive operator.